# timer working but control.value changes not working

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export function fleetCodeAsyncValidator(licenseCodeService: LicenseCodesService): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: FormControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return timer(500).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        if (!control || !control.value) {
          return of(null);
        }
        return licenseCodeService.getFleetCd(control.value).pipe(
          map(
            (response) => {
              return response && Object.keys(response).length > 0 ? null : { notValid: true };
            },
            (errors) => {
              return of({ notValid: true });
            }
          ),
          catchError((error) => {
            return of({ notValid: true });
          })
        );
      })
    );
  };
}
```

The code above triggers the form validation and the UI shows the appropriate message, but when using the value changes it seems to not work.

```
export function fleetCodeAsyncValidator(licenseCodeService: LicenseCodesService): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: FormControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return control.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap(() => {
        if (!control || !control.value) {
          return of(null);
        }
        return licenseCodeService.getFleetCd(control.value).pipe(
          map(
            (response) => {
              return response && Object.keys(response).length > 0 ? null : { notValid: true };
            },
            (errors) => {
              return of({ notValid: true });
            }
          ),
          catchError((error) => {
            return of({ notValid: true });
          })
        );
      })
    );
  };
}
```

I tried second method and its not working but the first one does. I want to use debounceTime instead of timer.